# qtmake - shared resources between two projects/targets

Tags: c++, qt, shared

I'm trying to set up directory with shared files but I ended up with `No rule to make target 'position.cpp', ...`. What am I doing wrong?

filesystem tree (simplified):

```
Project.pro client  server  shared

./client:
client.pro  main.cpp  main.h

./server:
main.cpp  main.h  server.pro

./shared:
position.cpp  position.h  shared.pri
```

Project.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS = client server
```

client.pro (server.pro looks similar):

```
LIBS += $$system(sdl2-config  --libs) -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_net
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += $$system(sdl2-config --cflags) -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic -std=c++11

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    main.h

include(../shared/shared.pri)
```

shared.pri:

```
SOURCES += \
    position.cpp

HEADERS += \
    position.h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The given error could occur when `make` fails to find the referenced `position.cpp` file. The reason is that it tries to find the `position.cpp` in the directory where the `.pro` and not the `.pri` file is. To fix it you might try to use `_PRO_FILE_PWD_` variable in your .pri file to properly set path to the `position.cpp(h)` files.